# libGDX, project build fail. Could not detemine java version '9.0.1'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, libgdx, project

I am new to libGDX, just planning to create a new project. but the generation of project fail with this error displayed

"Could not detemine java version '9.0.1'.

I have linked the SDK path like how I linked it in android studio. need help. I found it might be something to do with the gradle version. do you guys know how to let libGDX uses the latest gradle?

[image: Project Set up page]

Answer (score 1):

Check this [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4957), already in libgdx issue tracker.

According to this [discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/24457), Gradle update may solve this issue so wait for this [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698)  to be resolved.